# Map of Iceland not displayed

Tags: packages

I want to show the map of iceland with `\Iceland` via `\usepackage{countriesofeurope}`.  But it is not getting printed.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{countriesofeurope}
\begin{document}

\section{Iceland} 

\Iceland 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct usage is `\EUCountry[<options>]{<country>}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{countriesofeurope}
\begin{document}

\section{Iceland} 

\EUCountry[Scale=10]{Iceland} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Section 2 in the manual specifies that

> The countries themselves are available by a macro from the following list. The characters are at the position 128–166 in the Type 1 font `countriesofeurope.pfb` and also available with the `\char` primitive.

What does this mean? That `\Iceland` by itself will try to print a character in the current font, but in this case an error is raised because there is no default font encoding assigned for `\Iceland`. Adding

```
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\Iceland}{U}
```

would remove the error, but wouldn't print the required map anyway. You get it with

```
{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{countriesofeurope}\selectfont\Iceland}
```

but I guess you concur that `\EUCountry{Iceland}` (with possible scaling option) is easier. For one thing: this sequence of commands would only work with `pdflatex`, not with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.